# Passing query to a object, that contains bounded values

Tags: php, object, pdo

I am using PDO to connect with my MySQL db

So before in my users list i did:

- Build the query by conditions (online? new user? sex?)
- prepared the query
- bound the values to the query
- execute
- fetch in a while() to show the results

Now I am just calling a object, UserCollection, load it and foreach the output.

```
$list = new UserCollection( $connect );
$list->load();
```

like that. In load() is the standard query for now:

```
    $stmt = $this->_pdo->query( 'SELECT id FROM users' );
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

Theres no bounded variables to it, so it is not prepared.

Works fine, and it grabs just all the users.

Now what I wish to do is pass the query, that has been build to UserCollection() and use it to load() in the query.

I could do this easy, if the query was not bounded to variables, like the query above.

So what should I do if i want to pass a variable like this:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, id, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE sex=:sex
```

Then i would need to bind :sex, and i cant just write bindValue() as

1. the value is not inside the UserCollection object
2. sometimes it could be only WHERE firstname=:firstname and not    :sex, so it would throw error that I have bound a value that I dont use..

So what should I do here? what can i do?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could modify your load method:

```
function load($params = array()){
    $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare("*your sql here*");
    if (!empty($params)){
        foreach ($params as $param_key=>$param_value)
             $stmt ->bindParam($param_key, $param_value);
    }
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}
```

this way you don't have to modify existing code. To use it with new queries with arbitrarry number of parameters you'll just call it like:

```
$sex = 'male';
$firstname = 'Richard';
$params = array(':sex'=>&$sex, ':firstname'=>&$firstname);
$list->load($parameters);
```

Don't have PHP at hand, so can't test it, but I think that should work.